# JavaScript Cookies are not being set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I followed went through some related threads and also followed the tutorial on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html but I can't get my cookie to set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setcookie(name, value, days)
{
    if (days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="value+expires+;path=/";
}
</script>
```

Then in my  tag I have:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setcookie("testcookie", "test", 1);
</script>
</body>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I have cookies enabled, using FF and I can see cookies being created in real time by sites like Youtube but this one won't set at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The script contains several mistakes. Here's the corrected version (tested):

```
function setcookie(name, value, days)
{
  if (days)
  {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000); // ) removed
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); // + added
  }
  else
    var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"=" + value+expires + ";path=/"; // + and " added
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add the `toGMTString()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a + sign and a quote mark on this line:

```
document.cookie = name+"="value+expires+;path=/";
```

should be:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/";
```

I'd suggest you look in your browser's error console or your javascript debugger's console to see javascript errors.

Comment: Still no change, I always had the quotation after expires but missed it when I typed it up here. I added the + before value and tested but still not setting the cookie.

Comment: There are two other lines with mistakes, see my answer.

Comment: @SethHall - If you're not going to look in your browser's error console to see where your javascript errors are, then you might as well start typing with a blindfold on.  That should be the FIRST place you look when code isn't executing.  See Yogu's answer for some of your other errors, but next time look at the error console yourself to see your own errors.