# Javascript Cookie Not Setting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iis, cookies

I have an application that needs to pop a URL based on a Query String sent to it. Unfortunately, we can't insert any javascript into the application itself, but we can insert an iFrame that loads a page running javascript. There is a bug in the application where it loads the content in the iFrame twice within a couple seconds, which results in the URL popping twice.

To resolve this, I decided to set a cookie with an expiration. Before popping, I would check to see if the cookie exists, and if it does, prevent the pop from happening.

Unfortunately, my cookie is not being set. I've read a few threads about Javascript cookies trying to figure this out. The first thing I found is Chrome does not accept cookies from local files, so I set up an IIS server to host the page.

However, the cookie still is not being set. I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097423/javascript-cookies-are-not-being-set) to make sure my code was correct, and as far as I can tell, it should be correct.

The code for my page is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var isPopped;

function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}

function pop() {
var queryString = location.search.substring(1); //Get Query String from URL of iFrame source. The substring(1) strips off the ? and only takes the first substring. This can be modified to take more and the resulting string can be edited with Regular Expressions if more flexibility is required.
var urlToPop = "https://www.google.com/#" + queryString //Set URL to pop. 

    var recentVisitTrue=getCookie("visitRecent");
    if (recentVisitTrue != "") {
        isPopped = 1;
    } else {
       window.open(urlToPop,"_blank");
       setCookie("visitRecent", "true");
    }
}

function setCookie(cName,cValue) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(d.getTime() + 8000000);
var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cName) {
    var name = cName + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="pop();">
v0.32
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You didn’t define `d` in `date.setTime(d.getTime() + 8000000);`. Did you mean `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 8000000);`?

Comment: That's it! It works now. Wow, can't believe I missed that.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.